# Silverlight installed in Firefox 3, but not detected/activated

Tags: silverlight, firefox

As the title says really. We are working on a Silverlight banner on a redesign of our site and the Silverlight content works fine in all browsers except Firefox 3 (PC v3.0.7,8 or Mac v3.0.8). The Add-in is marked as having been installed, however.

The problem page is at:
http://clearvision.programx.co.uk/Schools/Students.aspx

(Note: we know of the crap HTML mark-up, that is a bug in SiteFinity, the CMS we're having to use. We have tried with and without this erroneous content with no effect.)

I've seen a number of reports (this one being particularly good: http://tempvariable.blogspot.com/2008/04/silverlight-and-firefox-3.html) about Firefox 3 having problems.

The SL control is Silverlight 1.0.

Any help much appreciated, I really do nto want to have to write alternative content for Firefox users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your Silverlight.js file and it was version 1.0 of the .js file. I think that upgrading to the [2.0 version of Silverlight.js file](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightjs) (which was updated for FF3) may solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you can tell, I'm a noob on Silverlight at the moment.